# WebView in Android fires standard browser

Tags: android, webview

I have created an Activity in Android for displaying websites. I used this code:

```
private WebView mWebview; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    mWebview = new WebView(this);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    mWebview.loadUrl("http://blablabla");
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    setContentView(mWebview);
```

But when I use it with for example www.bild.de, or its mobile version wap.bild.de, it fires the standard browser and gets out from my app. The same if I tap a link from that website. I don't want that. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code in a test project on my phone and it seems to work perfectly when loading the first page. It loaded wap.bild.de without any problems for the first time.

I did, however, experience the same problem that the default browser is launched when I tap on a link. To fix that, just add the following lines:

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url); // open link in the same web view.
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not really doing anything "wrong". Link clicks and redirects, by default, bring up the user's chosen Web browser instead of keeping them within your `WebView`.

To counteract this, you will need to add a `WebViewClient` implementation to your `WebView`, via `setWebViewClient()`. Your `WebViewClient` subclass will need to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to handle whichever URLs you want to keep in the `WebView`:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  if (/* url is one you want to keep in the WebView */) {
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return(true);
  }

  return(false);
}
```